# How to get object index in vue js when object property changed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My vue component code looks like this.

```
data: function () {
    return {   
        products: [ 
            { product_id: '', price: ''}, 
            { product_id: '', price: ''},  
        ],
    }
},
```

Now I want to get object index when v-model="product_id" changed. Is there any solution to get it?

```
<div v-for="(product, key) in products">
    <input type="text" v-model="product.product_id" />
    <input type="text" v-model="product.price" />
</div><!--  /.div -->
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by array object index?

Comment: You can use watch, with `deep: true`, and you don't need the index, you have the actual object reference. But if you want the index just use Array.findIndex() or lodash's equivalent.

Comment: @HarshPatel If the first product_id changed it want to get 0 index. if the second product_id changed than 1

Comment: @ZachLeighton Can you give me demo code?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just add some method that triggers on `@change` event?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
      { text: 'Learn Vue' },
      { text: 'Play around in JSFiddle' },
      { text: 'Build something awesome' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getIndex(index) {
     console.log(index)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(todo, index) in todos" @key="index">
    <input type="text" v-model="todo.text" @change="getIndex(index)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In v-model="todo.text" field. I'm using https://vue-multiselect.js.org/  multi picker field component, I can't pass an extra parameter in this field. I already created an issues see it please https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/933

Comment: @RakibulHasan then update your OP with that info. It would be also good if you create a fiddle with that plugin.

Comment: Sorry for this messy question. I've created a new one please see it 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877945/vue-js-how-to-watch-property-of-nested-object-and-get-index

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
data() {
    return {
    products: {  
            product: [ 
                { product_id: '1', price: '50'}, 
                { product_id: '2', price: '93'},  
            ],
            another_field: '',
    },
  }
},
watch: {
    'products.product.product_id'(newId) {
    this.products.another_field = this.products.product.findIndex(p => p.product_id == newId)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to get it automatic like Vue watch: {}. when v-model="product_id" changed

Comment: Sorry for my this messy question. I've created a new  one please see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877945/vue-js-how-to-watch-property-of-nested-object-and-get-index

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watch with something like this:

```
watch: {
   'products.product': {
       handler(newValue, oldValue) {
           // make sure it changed
           if(newValue != oldValue) {
              // get the row that changed
              let [rowChanged] = _.difference(newValue, oldValue);
              // find its index
              let arrayIndex = newValue.indexOf(rowChanged);
           }  
       },
       deep: true
   }
}
```

Something like this should work. If you want you can combine everything into a jsfiddle so we can see the whole .vue component.

Comment: I am not sure if __watch__ is the right approach because the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) have a WARNING:
_Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value._